# Paint on PDF via PDF.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, drawing, pdf-editor

We use the great library [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)

It would be really cool if you could paint on the pdf which gets displayed via pdf.js.

A commercial library would be ok, but open source is preferred.

With "paint on the pdf" I mean these operations:

- draw a red freehand line to emphasis parts
- Stamping with predefined stamps like "ok" (in green color)
- Writing simple text above the pdf like "Please call Mr x"

I guess to make drawing on the PDF fluent this needs be done:

- If the user paints on the PDF, then this gets done in JavaScript in the browser.
- There needs to be a way to save the drawing on the server side. This can be in any data format. Merging this into the pdf is not the goal. There should be two files: PDF and overlay.

I guess the other solution: "The drawing gets transferred to the server first. Then it gets stored, then it transferred to the client, there it gets rendered" is not fluent enough.

Up to now we use Django on the server side. But AFAIK this should not be relevant for this question.

Comment: Will this run on a server? Or does it need to work in web browsers too?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul thank you for your comment. I updated the question. Is not clear now? Please leave a comment if there is something not easy to understand.

Comment: Will the library be called by Node.js or similar?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul 
I updated the question: Up to now we use Django on the server side. I don't understand why you ask about Node.js. AFAIK it makes no difference which software runs on the server (for this question). Or am I missing something?

Comment: please let me know if u've found one